# Hoffman and Kunze's Exercises

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm using Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Alegrba.* I have completed the first chapter, and I am looking for someone's advice on the exercises for the book. The first chapter doesn't seem to have a lot of "theorem-proof" questions. Is that the general trend for the book? Are the exercises for further chapters along this vain as well? Does one need to supplement Hoffman and Kunze's book with exercises from another book. If som which book? I don't want to read another text from the scratch; any suggestions?

Also, there are no solutions available for chapters 7 onward. Are there any good alternative resources (with solutions) to do questions on Canonical Forms, Inner Product Spaces etc. Or are the exercises from Hoffman and Kunze for these units a must do?

Comment: The exercises in Hoffman and Kunze are good, you should be fine going through them. Yes, you should do the exercise from Canonical Forms and Inner Product Spaces, etc. If you really want solutions, try googling them for I'm sure they've nearly all been asked online before.

Comment: @DavidBowman Should I bother supplementing the exercises from H&K, especially for those from chapters 7 (canonical forms) onward? For instance, I read that Friedberg, Insel and Spence''s book has good exercises but while the book is fairly modern and thorough, they don't do a good job while covering units on canonical forms etc.

Comment: Just do as much math as you can

Comment: @DavidBowman Yes, I know. I love math, too. I'm a student of physics with theoretical leanings who wants to juggle both math and physics side by side. Also, I'm not even a physics major so I'm making the transition to physics, so I have to cover a lot of stuff outside of class as well. Yes, ideally I'd work out 2 books on LA side by side before tackling the advanced books but assuming I can't (I need to start with Herstein's Topics in Algerba too), should I really consider supplementing H and K's exercises? You're right though; the more the math the better!

Comment: Hmm. Honestly, I do not think it is necessary. If you still want to, you might consider Axler. His problems have a very different feel to them.

Comment: @DavidBowman Could you comment on the differing nature of problems in Axler's and Freidberg et al.'s books? Also, since we are on the topic, what about the exercises in Herstein? I simply wish to stick with this for now.

Comment: I don't know anything about Freidberg or Herstein, sadly.